# securing input language keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, input-languages

I use Windows 8 and I chose to use input language keyboard 134884362 (Latin American). But usually the computer changes to another keyboard and is very upseting. What should I do to prevent the machine to EVER change my keyboard having always my Latin American though my Windows display language is always English?
[image]

Comment: Where isn't just removing the other keyboards an option?

Comment: even removing all English keyboard it reappers

Comment: Please be specific.  What exactly reappears?  If you remove all Keyboards except one then there would be no keyboars that could reappear.

Comment: Keyboard Layout: is only Latin American. But again it appears others

Comment: If the Latin American keyboard layout is the only installed layout, another layout being used, does not make sense.  Please clarify your last statement.

Comment: For that reason I posted this message. I selected only LA keyboard so I don't understand why others are appearing. Please suggest what is wrong in my settings

Comment: Post a screenshot of the keyboard layouts you have installed in a comment.

Comment: ok, but which screenshot should I post? The one whose title is simply "Language"?

Comment: I don't know how to paste here in the comment. I tried to edit my original question but Superuser did not allow that because I don't have enough points. How can you see this? or what specific thing you need to know in order to help out?

Comment: I posted the screenshot